# Is jQueryUI compatible to jQuery 3? Migrate Plugin shows deprecations

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am runnig a `Symfony 2.8` based webpage which is currently using `jQuery 1.11.3`. I would like to update to `jQuery 3.2.1`, so I simply changed the import and added the Migration Plugin as well:

```
// Old
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


// New
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

My understanding is, that because of the Migration Plugin, there should be no problems with the existing scripts. All incompatibilities or BC breaks between jQuery 1.12 and 3 should be handled by the Plugin. **Is that correct?**

Indeed everything seems to work fine and the Plugin does not report any problems with my own scripts. **So it should be save to remove the Plugin (if I would only use these scripts), right?**

However, the Plugin reports several issues which seem to be caused by `jQueryUI`, e.g.:

```
JQMIGRATE: jQuery.expr[":"] is now jQuery.expr.pseudos
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js:62
get @ jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js:75
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
(anonymous) @ jquery-ui.min.js:6

JQMIGRATE: jQuery.unique is deprecated, use jQuery.uniqueSort
migrateWarn @ jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js:62
get         @ jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js:75
i           @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
_classes    @ jquery-ui.min.js:6
...
```

If I understand this correctly, `jQueryUI` uses some code (`jQuery.expr[":"]`) that that should be replaced (`jQuery.expr.pseudos`), **correct?**

**So, isn't `jQueryUI` compatible to `jQuery 3` at all?**

I removed the Migration Plugin in everthing still worked fine? How should this be handled? Is this something to worry about or just a warning?

Comment: Because of this issue, I patched the problems with jQuery UI and committed them here: https://github.com/DenisLabrecque/jQuery-UI-Fixed-for-3.5.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're warnings, so yes they're something to worry about, but they don't immediately break the code, as you've discovered.

If a feature is deprecated, it means the maintainer plans to remove it in future. The idea is that a deprecation warning gives you time and sufficient warning to alter your code before upgrading again, but doesn't cause you an immediate problem. Documentation, roadmaps and release notes of the project will usually contain information about deprecation and removals as well, so you can plan ahead.

Basically, you're fine for now but should plan to change your code in the medium term to avoid the deprecated functionality.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification! The second example in my question is explicitly named as *deprecation*, however the the first example says "X *is now* Y". Is this also a deprecation? It sound as if the code has already changed (rather than in a future version). What about the first question? Is is completely save to switch to v3 when using the Migration Plugin at the same time?

Comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/issues/204 suggests the first one is also a deprecation. Seems like they will fix the warning message at some later time.

Comment: it should be safe to switch to v3 with the plugin yes, that's the idea of it. Of course no complex code like this be 100% guaranteed to work (their automated tests don't have 100% coverage yet either according to GitHub) but in theory you should be fine. And with the benefit of the warnings so you can plan to replace your code and remove the need for the plugin in future.